# Target only one element within same classes with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a little issue:

```
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".suaugusi").click(function () {
            $(".activ-suaug, .activ-title-suaugusi").slideToggle("slow");
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

How to use code above, to make sure, taht it works only on one DIV with class **.suaugusi?** I have 12 div's with same classes, but i need, that it would activate only on clicked one. How to do so?

**EDIT**

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 uzsiemimas">
  <div class="portfolio-item suaugusi">
    <div class="item-inner">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="<?php the_sub_field('nuotrauka'); ?>" alt="">
      <h4 class="activ-title-suaugusi"><?php the_sub_field('pavadinimas'); ?></h4>
      <div class="overlay"></div>
      <div class="activ-menu activ-suaug">
        <?php if( have_rows( 'uzsiemimo_veiklos') ): while ( have_rows( 'uzsiemimo_veiklos') ) : the_row(); ?>
        <a href="<?php the_sub_field('nuoroda'); ?>">
          <div class="activ-element">
            <?php the_sub_field( 'pavadinimas');?>
          </div>
        </a>
        <?php endwhile; else : endif; ?>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Show the HTML. Relationship between suaugusi and activ-suaug,

Comment: Try `$(this).slideToggle("slow");`

Comment: depends on how the html is structured... could you add the html please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `this` keyword within the event handler to refer to the element which raised the event, then `find()` to retrieve the specific elements you want to target. Try this:

```
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".suaugusi").click(function () {
            $(this).find('.activ-suaug, .activ-title-suaugusi').slideToggle("slow");
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: it hides whole div, how to hide only classes within it?

Answer (score 3):

As `activ-suaug` and `activ-title-suaugusi` are child elements of `suaugusi` you should use `.find()` to traverse up to them, then perform the desired operation.

*Use*

```
$(".suaugusi").click(function () {
    $(this).find(".activ-suaug, .activ-title-suaugusi").slideToggle("slow");
});
```